# How to transfer old email message from PLESK to cPanel

Tags: email, cpanel, plesk

I have redirected a domain from PLESK to another server (cPanel) and also I have transferred the code from PLESK TO cPanel. Now my website is running well. I have created my email on cPanel and i am using webmail to access my email account.

But want to transfer old email messages from PLESK to cPanel. I have searched and found that email messages are stored on PLESK on this location:

```
# /var/qmail/
```

Is there any way to transfer email email messages from PLESK to cPanel?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch mail from your PLESK server and have it imported into cPanel.

1. Simply login to your cPanel
2. Access your webmail and access Horde
3. Once logged in, on the left hand side, click OPTIONS then Mail
4. On the center of the screen under “*Message Options*” click “*Fetch Mail*”
5. Create a new account, enter your details from your email account located on your PLESK server *(for the incoming/outgoing servers, use your PLESK server hostname)*
6. Email will then begin to be downloaded into your cPanel inbox.

That should do the trick :)

Comment: Horde Fetch Mail is no longer available. Read more https://wiki.horde.org/FAQ/User/IMP?referrer=FAQ%25%252FUser#toc23

Answer (score 0):

**Horde doesn't have the Fetch Mail option** anymore.
So, the easiest solution is **manual transfer** using Outlook or Thunderbird.

How to move email from any server into cPanel **use an** **IMAP client** like Microsoft Outlook or Thunderbird?

First, configure each new email account on cPanel (including any sub-folders). Next, configure your IMAP client (Outlook or Thunderbird) with each email account on each server.
One account for the old account (if it is not already there) and one account for the new account created with cPanel.

**You may find it easier to use the actual IP addresses of each respective server to avoid name resolution issues.**

[image]

Replace example.com with **IP address** (use ping example.com on your CMD console to find out the IP of the old server)

After that, you just need to drag-and-drop the old messages from the old account into the new account on Outlook or Thunderbird and delete the old account.

When finishing with all accounts, change your domain DNS to the new cPanel hosting server and you're done.

**It will be downtime?** 
Depends on the number of email boxes you have to transfer and on other websites or applications you have to move from the old domain name. Normally it should work fast enough to not have any problems but I suggest doing this after working hours.